# On change ajax call not happening

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am working on HTML `table`. I have a `form` inside which has a `select`which has options for `ALL` and `Biscuts`. On first load I am populating a table which is working fine.

When I choose an option from the select I want to make a AJAX call on `onchange` event but it is not happening. I am trying to dynamically update my table when the user selects any option from the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: "CategoryOlWiseFilter",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(tableData) {
      addTable(tableData);
    }
  });

  $('#CategoryName').change(function() { //this one is not working
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    alert(selectedOption);
    $.ajax({
      url: "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        categoryName: selectedOption,
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form>
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-4 brder p-2">
        <h5>Category</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 text-center brder">
        <select class="form-control offset-4 col-4" id="CategoryName">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Biscuits</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="table table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id="HourlysalesSummary"></table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**my backend Servlet Code**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
// i will use the here categoryNamePost here
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String categoryNamePost = request.getParameter("categoryName");
    System.out.println("Category" + categoryNamePost);
    getServletContext().setAttribute("categoryNameAttribute", categoryNamePost);
}
```

In total I am making 3 AJAX calls

1. Populates data for all the `Categories`
2. Send the data back to server that which category is selected - this is not working
3. Populate a new table on the basis of the selected option

My main issue is the second one because the AJAX call is not successful. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the third call depends on the second one being complete, as it needs to add the data, as such I would assume you need to put the third AJAX request within the `success` handler of the second one

Comment: but the issue is the second one is not working..let us assume there is no 3rd ajax call

Comment: How have you determined the second AJAX request isn't working? It has no action after it completes. Have you checked the console for errors? If no data is being saved on your server then this would appear to be a problem with your server logic, not JS

Comment: the change event fires when you focus out of the select box

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan look i have edited teh code, i have removed my 3rd ajax which is not need for now, and with second ajax i am sending data back to server

Comment: @manishthakur that's all well and good, but doesn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan after sending the data `categoryName` via ajax in my servlet i am getting it as `request.getparameter("categoryName")` i have put a console there which is not showing any thing

Comment: Can you share your backed Web method (ItemCategoryWiseFilter()), the code inside method is not required.

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya done

Comment: @Sergej so what can i do

Comment: @manishthakur Can you try to add code ` 'contentType: "application/json", categoryName: JSON.stringify(selectedOption), success: function(response) {   // ...   }' `

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya whereat the post ajax call?

Comment: @manishthakur Yes correct.

Comment: The code you have posted is working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/g1sf3wha/
request on change is firing.

Comment: yupp its working fine now....really sorry guys i was making some stupid mistakes really sorry i waste your time

Comment: @manishthakur You would be better of deleting this question. The problem is not in your question and the answers did not fix your problem. This question wont help others, which is what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @manishthakur Also you shouldn't accept/up vote answers that do not answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your change trigger again call the addtable function,if i assume that it is populating your table correctly.you were also using an extra comma after selectedOption.

```
 <table id="table" class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" ><b>NEED</b>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
  <tbody id="table2"></tbody>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <script>
      $('#CategoryName').change(function() { 
        var selectedOption = this.value;
         alert(selectedOption);
         $.ajax({
            url: "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
            categoryName: selectedOption},
             success: function(tableData) {
           // if addtable(tableData) is not populating html
                $('#table2').html(data);
             }
          });
```

`

Comment: nop...after selecting the dropdown alert is triggered but ajax is not happening

Comment: there can be a problem in the url or addtable function,try to populate directly without using function

Comment: no error on console as well as on my backend.....and why are you putting addtable into post request that is for only posting data back to server that's it,my issue is  that `categoryName` this value is not received by server

Comment: its the response which you are getting on your ajax request and if addtable is not populating your html then you can directly populate it from here

Comment: ya its working fine ..i have made mistakes in my source code sorry for that :(

Comment: please consider the answer one more time this can possibly solve your problem